# Is there any possible way to generate a notication from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I need to generate a titlbar notification from a broadcast receiver.
or
an alert dialogue with a notification sound

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: Do some R&D at your end.

Comment: This is not a question. You're telling us what you need, and expect us to solve it for you. What did you try so far? What happened? Why didn't it work? Have you read the most fundamental Android developer documentation? Maybe start here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: @JHH There's no need to be this rude, I'm a newbie in Android app development world. I have Questions, and i expect answers. If your not interested in giving answers, don't comment anything at all.

Comment: What on earth made you think I am rude? I merely pointed out some hints at what you should add in order to get any answers of quality. It's expected that questions contain a concise problem description. "I want to achieve X so I tried this code Y and this code Z but it doesn't work because of A." Your question has nothing of this. If you have a broadcast receiver and you failed to create a notification from it, you should have posted your onReceive method and what you've tried so far.

Besides, I pointed out useful resources to read, that should get you started. I am trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, an example from my latest project:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
Notification myNotification;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent();

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, MY_NOTIFICATION_ID,
            myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);



    myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("Game Time!")
            .setContentText("Where Amazing happens")
            .setTicker("Hello !")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .build();

    notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);

}
```

you can also call another activity from your BroadcastReceiver.

Hope this help!

Answer (score -1):

Notification can be generated in an Activity or a Service. Modify your broadcast receiver and use its Context to generate it. Better post your code :)

Comment: Notifications can be created from anywhere as long as you have a Context available.

Comment: @JHH oops, my bad. Sorry.